# image index out of range PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

This program creates a 600 x 600 image and then initializes four points.
Each of these four points then move 10% of the distance towards the point
closest to them in a clockwise direction. After each move, the program draws
a line between each of the pairs of points. The program stops when the points
are sufficiently close together.

```
from PIL import Image
from math import *

# Initial white image
n=600
img = Image.new("RGB", (n, n), (255, 255, 255))

# Draws a line between (p1x, p1y) and (p2x, p2y)
def drawLine(p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y):
    t = 0.0
    while t < 1.0:
        x = int (n * (p1x + t * (p2x - p1x)))
        y = int (n * (p1y + t * (p2y - p1y)))
        img.putpixel((x, y),(0, 0, 255)) 
        t += 0.001          

# Initialize four points
P1 = (x1, y1) = (0.0, 0.0)
P2 = (x2, y2) = (1.0, 0.0)
P3 = (x3, y3) = (1.0, 1.0)
P4 = (x4, y4) = (0.0, 1.0)

# Draws lines
for counter in range(600):
    x1 = .9 * x1 + .1 * x2
    y1 = .9 * y1 + .1 * y2
    drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    x2 = .9 * x2 + .1 * x3
    y2 = .9 * y2 + .1 * y3
    drawLine(x2, y2, x3, y3) # Doesn't work
    x3 = .9 * x3 + .1 * x4
    y3 = .9 * y3 + .1 * y4
    drawLine(x3, y3, x4, y4) # Doesn't work
    x4 = .9 * x4 + .1 * x1
    y4 = .9 * y4 + .1 * y1
    drawLine(x4, y4, x1, y1)


# Saves image in Lab09.png
img.save("Lab09.png")
img.show("Lab09.png")
```

So basically the lines commented with # Doesn't work cause this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/e154675/Desktop/Lab09.py", line 41, in <module>
    drawLine(x2, y2, x3, y3)
  File "/Users/e154675/Desktop/Lab09.py", line 25, in drawLine
    img.putpixel((x, y),(0, 0, 255))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1518, in putpixel
    return self.im.putpixel(xy, value)
IndexError: image index out of range
```

I'd like to know how to fix this issue and what's causing it.
(I'm on a macbook pro using IDLE)

Thank you guys so much!!! :) <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `drawLine(x2, y2, x3, y3)`, you have `x2 = .9 * x2 + .1 * x3`, where `x2` and `x3` are initially defined to be `1.0`.  Thus, at the time of the function call, `x2` is 1.  The first time through your line-drawing loop, when `t=0.0`, you'll set `x` to `int (n * (p1x + t * (p2x - p1x)))`, which works out to `1.0 * 600`, or 600.  So, you'll end up calling `img.putpixel` using a pixel coordinate whose x component is 600.  On a 600x600 image, the outside corner is at (599,599).  The result is going to be an IndexError.

To test this theory, you can try making your image one pixel bigger and see if that helps:

```
img = Image.new("RGB", (n+1, n+1), (255, 255, 255))
```

Alternatively, move your points (`P1`, etc.) further away from the edges of your image, like making them (0.1,0.1) and (0.9,0.9) or something.

Answer (score 1):

From the Python documentation:

> exception IndexError Raised when a sequence subscript is out of range.

I'd start off with putting the offending code block in a try: except: block, maybe try printing the index it's trying to access first and working back from there.